# How to set a Kotlin while loop stop after 3 times?

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin, I want to condition my while loop stop after 3 times, please, help! Also it should ask user to quit game or continue

```
val randomNumber: String = Random().nextInt(10).toString()
var guess= true
println("Welcome to the Number Guess Game")
println("Please guess number between 1 to 10")


do{
    val User=readLine()!!.toString()
    if(User==randomNumber){
        guess=false
    }
    else{"Sorry Please Try Again"}

}while(guess)
println("Congratulation You have guessed the right number.")
```

Comment: Here is a link to the [Kotlin control flow documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html). Check out the for loop, and the concept of `break`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
var correct = false
var tries = 0

val randomNumber = Random().nextInt(10) + 1
println("Welcome to the number guess game")
println("Please guess a number between 1 to 10")

do {
    val input = readLine() ?: break
    val guess = input.toIntOrNull()

    tries += 1
    correct = guess == randomNumber
    if (!correct) {
        println("Sorry please try again!")
    }
} while (!correct && tries < 3)

if (correct) {
    println("Congratulation You have guessed the right number.")
} else {
    println("Sorry. The answer was $randomNumber")
}
```

Things to note:

- `Random.nextInt(10)` will actually return a number between 0 and 9 so you need to add 1.
- If `readLine()` returns null, there is nothing more to read, so `readLine() ?: break` will either return a string or stop the loop immediately if `readLine()` is null.
- `while (!correct && tries < 3)` means continue while the guess is not correct and `tries` has not reached 3. `tries` is increased by 1 (`tries += 1`) on each guess. `correct` keeps track of whether the correct number has been guessed (`guess == randomNumber`).
- `toIntOrNull`  turns a String to an Int but returns null if it is not actually a number.
- `$randomNumber` puts the value of `randomNumber` directly in a string so you can print it as part of a message.

Comment: Thank you so much for help. Could you please help little more, I also want this program to ask user either to quit or continue game again. Please help